# Is the given language: (regular|context-free|etc)

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

> Assume E = {a, b}. Let L0 = {(b^(n))(a^(2n)) : n >= 0}. Let L = ((NOT OPERATION)L0)
>
> Is L regular, context-free but not regular, or not context-free? Prove your answer.

I'm looking for what L would be, and how to describe it in a similar fashion of how L0 was described in the question, along with the answer.

The explanation is very important to me, if you'd like to contribute, please be specific. I'm looking to understand this material for a test.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, we can tell you are interested in what `L` would be.  That is afterall the answer to your homework assignment.  It seems unfair to you to just tell you.  What do you have so far?   What are you missing in your understanding?

Comment: @Kirk: L isn't the answer, it's a fundamental step that I'm failing to understand. Also, it's not my homework assignment, I'm working book problems to prepare for a test that is tomorrow night. I need to know what L would be, because I'm only currently guessing that it is the set of a,b combinations that is not in L0. After knowing what L is, I can most likely determine if it is regular/context-free on my own. What seems unfair to me is for you to assume I'm surfing for homework problems.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain you using layman's language and hints for you to do formalize it.

`L` is a language with all the strings of alphabet `E={a,b}`which are not in language `L0`
This is a not a regular language.

Strings in `L` are all the strings which end at non-final states of DFA of L0. 
But as you can't build DFA/NFA for L0, you can't have a DFA for L too.

Reason: In `L0` one unbound number n, which need to be stored after look at all b's then use it while checking a's, DFA have no memory.
You can't write a regular expression for above language.

Using Pumpping lemma L is not a Context Free Language

S=`ab` is a string in L
Using PL I'll divide in into 5 parts

```
S=uvxyz

u="" v=a x="" y=b z=""
```

Now for `n=0`
new String is `S(n=0)=""` `which is not in L`.

if we divide ab into

```
   u="" v="" x=a y=b z=""
```

Now for `n=2` `S(n=2)=abb` `which is not in L`

So L is not CFG.

PS: Let me know if you find any hole in m

Comment: As L = ((NOT(L0)) and we are determining the properties of L, and NOT the properties of L0, I'm quite sure you didn't read the problem entirely. You wrote a CFG for L0. Also, as explained to Kirk, this isn't a homework. I'm reviewing for a test and I am working problems out of the book that haven't been assigned.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've learned the pumping lema.
But its a way to tell whether the language is regular.
And remember that if L0 is regular then L1 is regular too since you can make a dfa of L1 by swapping the final and initial stats of the L0 dfa.

Consinder any example of L0 where b^m a^2m and this string is big enough for pumping lema.

Divide the example into three parts xyz.

where |xy| < m (number of elements in the substring xy)
and |y| >= 1.

Since the chunk xy < m it must be all b's since there are b^m b's.

now lets pump y 0 times.

x y^0 z has so if your lang was bbbaaaaaa and |y|=1 ur lang becomes bbaaaaaa meaning that now it follow b^n a^3n. Which makes it not a regex.

Meaning that L1 is not a regex 2.